# When exactly does Java implicitly allocate heap memory?

Tags: java, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I distantly recall that one design decision of Java was to make heap allocations explicit, with `new` keyword (don't quote me on that, please).

It does deviate from this decision, at the very least, in two cases:

1. Passing varargs to a function (`Array` is implicitly allocated),
2. Assigning a primitive type to a boxed value/argument (autoboxing).

Are there other cases, and what are they? Exhaustive list is preferred.

My googling only revealed a basic articles about Java memory management.